# What are the limitations of Opensource ehcache?

Tags: java, scalability, ehcache, terracotta

I am looking for terracotta ehcache,

I want to know the limitations of opensource distributed ehcache.
**Does opensource distributed ehcache version has any limitations on number of Terracotta servers in partitioned topology?**
Are there any limitations on
 1. Number of objects in cluster
 2. max size of object in cluster
 3. max number of active terracotta servers
 4. max number of passive nodes under one active server
 5. Does opensource supports infinite linear scalability?If not upto what point it supports?
 6. Are there any limitations on High availability, Reliability, Consistency, Cache patterns like    write through\write back ?
 7. Does opensource version supports local and global transaction?

If there are any other limitations of opensource version please tell me.